# Custom Authentication to Add API on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-security, jersey

I use Users API on Google AppEngine (java).

I have a core servlet - /api - (JAXB Jersey Implemented) which exposes CRUD operations. Currently,  allows me to define that only logged in users can access that. So, users who have logged in on the site using OpenID or Google Federated Login can login and access that through the app.

Now, I want to publish API to the developers - /dev/api. We generate an unique API key for them to acsess the application.

How do I expose the same /api functionality under HTTP basic authentication without compromising the existing functionality? App Engine does not support custom security roles ().
How do I implement HTTP basic authentication? Should I use a filter on /dev/api and restrict in that filter?

Comment: <filter>
       <filter-name>BasicAuthFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>com.agilecrm.BasicAuthFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>BasicAuthFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/dev/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

This was simple.

I created a different filter (BasicAuthFilter) for my new URL pointing to the same Jersey resource.

It fixed it.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a more complete description and complete configuration example so this can be of some use to future users?